# Parsing X509 Distinguished Name

Tags: python, openssl, x509, pyopenssl

My Python web app receives from the web server the client's Distinguished Name (taken from client's certificate) in the format (possibly X509 standard format?):

```
/C=BR/ST=Minas Gerais/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/CN=www.test.com
```

Is this some kind of standard? Can I (safely) parse this string with pyOpenSSL and build a X509Name from it? Or maybe some other library? I am just interested in the CN...

Comment: `CN=www.test.com` - putting a DNS name in the `CN` is deprecated. It belongs in a `SAN`.

Comment: Think of it as a display name or a friendly name. In your case, use the friendly name of "Internet Widgits".

Comment: Can't you use pyOpenSSL? It returns X509Name-objects, which do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like python-ldap can parse these kinds of strings using the dn module (DN = Distinguished Name):

```
>>> ldap.dn.str2dn('cn=Michael Str\xc3\xb6der,dc=stroeder,dc=com',flags=ldap.DN_FORMAT_LDAPV3)
[[('cn', 'Michael Str\xc3\xb6der', 4)], [('dc', 'stroeder', 1)], [('dc', 'com', 1)]]
```

Source: https://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap-dn.html

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is a standard. The notation is defined in [RFC 4514](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt). You can parse it according to RFC, extract CN part and then use its value. Unfortunately I can't tell you about python libraries for this.

Comment: I haven't read the whole thing, but the examples doesn't seems to be in the same format. For instance, RFC shows `CN=James \"Jim\" Smith\, III,DC=example,DC=net`, that uses ',' as separator, and not '/'. Maybe what I got was some specific OpenSSL format?

Comment: @Ivella Maybe - I am not an expert in Open***. The other name of Distinguished Name is RDN. Search for "RDN RFC" and you'll find several different RFCs describing the text representation of the RDN.